# MAC Address spoofing/cloning wireless router

Tags: router, wlan

I need a wireless router that can spoof MAC addresses.

I want to connect to a network which only allows certain MAC addresses. I have access to this network with the MAC address of my Ethernet adapter. Now I want to connect to the network also with my wireless adapter.

So I need the functionality to spoof the MAC address of my WIFI adapter when connected to the wireless router which is connected to the restricted network.

Most wireless routers I know of do not support this feature. Is there one that does?

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: Below 100 dollar would be nice.

Comment: My only question before answering this post is.  Do you have permission to access this network via this method?  This can be a major security loophole.

Comment: Yes, I have....

Comment: Why not simply request that the MAC of your wireless NIC be added to the approved MAC ID list?  This would seem to be a much more secure idea from a network administration viewpoint.   As this hardware request goes against everything I know on the subject of network security and administration, I am ethically inclined to just walk away from this one.

Answer (score 3):

My router that I use has this feature. It is called MAC cloning.
They currently go for less than $30 on Amazon. They are a bit dated but will give you an idea what to look for.

[Asus - RT-N12B1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005EIH4DE)

Comment: But is it MAC cloning for every connected device or only for the WAN link? Maybe you could provide a screenshot of the setting.

Comment: It is a specific setting on the internet connection page that allows you to clone the mac address or set the mac address of your wan port on your router.  This is actually fairly common on most of the routers I have seen.  I have an Asus RT-N66R and it definitely has this feature.

Comment: Too bad. That is not what I need. I do not want to clone the link to the internet port.

Comment: I am confused as to what exactly you are asking then. It does clone the mac address of the machine you hit "clone" on for the WAN port. Essentially reporting that router as the NIC card from that machine.

Comment: @DanV: The WAN link is the port to the internet. I am looking for a way to spoof the connected LAN.

Comment: @DanV juergen's network is restricted to certain devices. This is done by only allowing certain MAC addresses to connect to the network. juergen needs a WiFi adapter that lets them specify the MAC address to use when connecting to the network - not when connecting the network to the Internet, which is what the WAN MAC is.

Comment: If you look at the specs of the ASUS you'll see it is a repeater as well. It has repeater mode. You can connect it to the original router that faces the internet. Then all devices can connect to the ASUS. It takes a bit of thinking to correctly set this up. But it is capable, I have done it with this router. But in a previous comment by NZK this will open up a restricted network to unintended holes.